# Use Twig (Timber) in Wordpress - Uncaught exception - can't find template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, twig

I want to use twig in wordpress plugins with the plugin timber.

The twig templates should be include in the themes directory and in my plugins I want to use these templates.

directory:

-wp-content

--plugins

---my-plugin

--theme

---templates

This is how I use the timber (twig) engine in my plugins:

```
$content.= \Timber::compile('templates/startseite_kleine_kachel.twig', $postData);
```

But I get this errormessage:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message
>   'Unable to find template "templates/startseite_kleine_kachel.twig"

I try this in the functions.php:

```
Timber::$dirname = 'templates';
```

Nothing works - only if I include my twig templates in my plugin folder. But that isn't so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

I delete this line from my functions.php

```
Timber::$dirname = 'templates';
```

Edit the folder name of templates into views and change the compile function into this:

```
$content.= \Timber::compile('startseite_kleine_kachel.twig', $postData);
```